# How do I clean up my sub menu code?

Tags: jquery, code-cleanup

I am trying to slide down a sub menu when hovering over a#about and keep the sub menu visible until hovering over another option.

I also want to hide the sub menu if not hovering over a#about or nav#about. Help please.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a#about').hover(function(){
        $('nav#about').slideDown();
    });

    $('nav#about').hover(function(){
        $('nav#about').slideDown();
    });

    $('a#home').hover(function(){
        $('nav#about').slideUp();
    });

    $('a#products').hover(function(){
        $('nav#about').slideUp();
    });

    $('a#contact').hover(function(){
        $('nav#about').slideUp();
    });
});
```

=========================================
edited to include the html

```
<nav id="main" class="left">
    <a id="home" class="left active">Home</a>
    <a id="about" class="left" href="#">About</a>
    <a id="products" class="left" href="#">Products</a>
    <a id="contact" class="left" href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>

<nav id="about" class="left">
    <a href="#"></a><br />
    <a href="#"></a><br />
    <a href="#"></a><br />
    <a href="#"></a><br />
    <a href="#"></a><br />
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you also post your HTML so we can see how it's structured.

Comment: Did you miss a `.` or `#` before `nav` on `nav#about` selector?

Comment: @fardjad I assume he's using HTML5, so the `nav` selector would be valid: http://html5doctor.com/nav-element/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That's why I asked `did you miss it`.

Comment: Thanks Roy and fardjad.
I've edited my post to include the HTML, Its actually really simple what I'm trying to do but my code isn't right.

Comment: @RaphaelSundar You are using IDs that are repeated on your page, it should be only *once* a page, so you must change the ID of the nav to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to slide down a sub menu when hovering over a#about and
>   keep the sub menu visible until hovering over another option

Assuming all navigation `divs` have class attribute of `nav` and the navigation links are wrapped in a `div` or `nav` tag like this:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a id="about" ...>About</a>
    <a id="home" ...>Home</a>
    <a id="products" ...>Products</a>
    <a id="contact" ...>Contact</a>
    <div class="nav" id="div-about" ...>...</div>
</div>
```

you can do something like this:

```
var menuTimeout;
$('#navigation a, #navigation .nav').hover(function() {
    hovered_div = $('#navigation #' + 'div-' + $(this).attr('id').replace('div-',''));
    $('#navigation .nav').not(hovered_div).hide();
    (hovered_div.css('display') == 'none') && hovered_div.slideDown();
    clearTimeout(menuTimeout);
}, function() {
       menuTimeout = setTimeout(function() { $('#navigation .nav').slideUp(); }, 1000);
   });
});
```

It basically binds to `hover` event of `anchors` and elements of `nav` class and hides all the `nav` divs except the current div (the hovered one) and slidesDown the hovered div if it's not visible, also when navigation divs or anchors are not hovered, it slides up the divs after 1 second using `setTimeout()`.

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XA72V/2/).